# Calling a Derived Class' method

Tags: c++

Can I call a Derived Class's method from the base class in C++?  If so, how can I do that?

Thank you.

Comment: Note that [it's not a good idea](http://www.artima.com/cppsource/nevercall.html) to call virtual functions [from the base class constructor](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/strange-inheritance.html#faq-23.5) or [the base class destructor](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/strange-inheritance.html#faq-23.7).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Attempting to call the method from within the base class will call the derived class's implementation, provided it is virtual.

```
class Base {
public:
  void do_stuff() {
    print_me();
  }

  virtual void print_me() { std::cout << "Base" << std::endl; }
};

class Child : public Base {
  virtual void print_me() { std::cout << "Child" << std::endl; }
};

int main() {
  Base* b = new Child();
  b->do_stuff(); // prints "Child"
}
```

Comment: How does this resolve if you have an instance of Base and multiple derived classes, and you call `do_stuff()`?

Comment: @Rafe OOP doesn't work that way. If you have an *instance* of Base, then it will use the method declared in Base. If you have an instance of one of the derived classes, it will use the derived class's method, provided it has declared one and the method is `virtual`.

Comment: ah, I see, I was thinking for some reason that `print_me()` wasn't defined in Base.

Comment: Okay that seemed to work.  This is much more helpful than Java.

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't mean only virtual calls (which are sometimes expensive), you also might call directly any method of any type in inheritance tree. Just `static_cast` or `dynamic_cast` `this` into desired type and call. But note that using `static_cast` is unsafe: *you must be sure **at compile time*** that this conversion and following call will be correct and safe at runtime (`dynamic_cast` will check it at runtime).

A little bit of simple code:

```
struct A {
    void foo();
};

struct B : A {
    void bar() { std::cout << "B::bar()" << std::endl; }
};

void A::foo() {
    static_cast<B*>(this)->bar();
}

int main() {
    A a;
    a.foo();
    return 0;
}
```

The output will be

> B::bar()

Check it out, no problems.

Also look at [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern).